# Probability of picking $2$ diamonds and $1$ non-diamond

Tags: probability

I'm having trouble understanding when to use combinations for counting, and when to multiply probabilities. Say the question is what's the probability of drawing $2$ diamonds and one card that isn't a diamond.

Why is one of these approaches wrong:

1. $$\dfrac{_{13}C_2\,\cdot\, _{39}C_1}{_{52}C_3}$$
   Here, I am choosing $2$ diamonds from the $13$ diamonds, times choosing $1$ non-diamond from the $39$ non-diamonds, all over the total number of ways you can choose $3$ cards.
2. $$\frac{13}{52}\cdot\frac{12}{51}\cdot\frac{39}{50}$$
   Here, first the probability of choosing $1$ diamond, then the second diamond from the remaining $51$ cards and $12$ diamonds, and then finally choosing one non-diamond from the remaining $50$ cards.

These both give $2$ different answers. They're off by a factor of $3$. Which is correct? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first approach is correct.  For the second approach, you have assumed the order DDN (diamond,diamond,non-diamond) but ignored DND and NDD.